# menu item not shown as action android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, menu, material-design, android-toolbar

The Toolbar (Actionbar) menu is not shown as action, even-though I am having only one manu item..!!
 this is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />   

</menu>
```

and I am using the support actionbar: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    local:theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     />
```

And I am setting actionbar with the following lines:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

[image: sscreen looks like]

Then whats wrong in my code? I am using the attribute shoAsAction="ifRoom" , but why it is not shown as action in the actionbar..? can anybody help me?

Comment: you inflate the menu in onmenucrreate?

Comment: yup, inflated, and it is shown when I select the menu button!! I will update my question with  whch is showing the menu.

Comment: I want to show the icon there.

Comment: menu icon itself is not displayed???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

For example

```
 <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
```

**EDIT**

**FOR APP COMPACT LIBRARY**

```
use `app:showAsAction="always"` instead of `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`
```

Comment: changing "android" with "app" worked. can u tell me , what is the difference there? if update your answer I can accept it